# Diagrams 3 and 4 in RFC 6749 (OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework)

Tags: oauth-2.0, rfc

In this [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749), I struggle to understand the diagrams in Figures 3 (Authorization Code Flow) and 4 (Implicit Grant Flow).

In both cases at point (B), it says "The authorization server authenticates the resource owner (via the user-agent)". The (B) arrow has two ends, one towards Resource owner and one towards Authorization server.

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |   Owner  |
 |          |
 +----------+
      ^
      |
     (B)
 +----|-----+          Client Identifier      +---------------+
 |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI ---->|               |
 |  User-   |                                 | Authorization |
 |  Agent  -+----(B)-- User authenticates --->|     Server    |
 |          |                                 |               |
 |         -+----(C)-- Authorization Code ---<|               |
 +-|----|---+                                 +---------------+
   |    |                                         ^      v
  (A)  (C)                                        |      |
   |    |                                         |      |
   ^    v                                         |      |
 +---------+                                      |      |
 |         |>---(D)-- Authorization Code ---------'      |
 |  Client |          & Redirection URI                  |
 |         |                                             |
 |         |<---(E)----- Access Token -------------------'
 +---------+       (w/ Optional Refresh Token)

                 Figure 3: Authorization Code Flow (actual)
```

It seems to me that the arrow should go from Resource owner to Authorization server, as the RO is the one that has to actively enter his credentials.

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |   Owner  |
 |          |
 +----------+
      v
      |
     (B)
 +----|-----+          Client Identifier      +---------------+
 |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI ---->|               |
 |  User-   |                                 | Authorization |
 |  Agent  -+----(B)-- User authenticates --->|     Server    |
 |          |                                 |               |
 |         -+----(C)-- Authorization Code ---<|               |
 +-|----|---+                                 +---------------+
   |    |                                         ^      v
  (A)  (C)                                        |      |
   |    |                                         |      |
   ^    v                                         |      |
 +---------+                                      |      |
 |         |>---(D)-- Authorization Code ---------'      |
 |  Client |          & Redirection URI                  |
 |         |                                             |
 |         |<---(E)----- Access Token -------------------'
 +---------+       (w/ Optional Refresh Token)

                 Figure 3: Authorization Code Flow (more correct?)
```

Anyway, I don't understand what this double arrow is supposed to mean. Is this a typo? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the user-agent (the browser) tries to reach the resource owner, but then it is being *redirected* to authorization server. So the 'B' arrow should *not* be from the resource owner to the authorization server.